# How can I improve my script which copies a screenshot I create in Flameshot and pastes that screenshot into a Google Drawing?

Tags: bash, screenshot

My rudimentary Bash script below is a little slow and a little unreliable. Do you have any suggestions for improving it?

```
google-chrome-stable -new-window https://docs.google.com/drawings/d/the_rest_of_a_URL_to_a_Google_Drawing_I_have_previously_created
sleep 0.2

xdotool key alt+Tab
sleep 1.5

flameshot gui -r >screenshot_that_my_script_creates.png && xdotool key alt+Tab && sleep 4.0 && xdotool key ctrl+v
```

My Bash script above allows me to create a screenshot with [Flameshot](https://github.com/flameshot-org/flameshot) and then annotate that screenshot in a [Google Drawing](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/179740?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en) which I have previously created. That Google Drawing has some tools—such as arrows and text boxes—that I like to use to annotate my screenshots, located around the outside of the margins of that Google Drawing itself so that they are readily available for me to drag onto my Google Drawing.

As you can see, my Bash script first loads a Google Drawing I have previously created. I have done this to decrease my need to wait for my Google Drawing to load (because it usually takes at least a few seconds for my Google Drawing to load). See, in Flameshot I usually drag a rectangle to choose the particular part of the screen I want to annotate. That process usually takes me at least a couple of seconds.

Comment: You could use selenium webdriver to make screenshots . or run [`chrome --headless --disable-gpu --screenshot https://docs.google.com/drawings/d/the_rest_of_a_URL_to_a_Google_Drawing_I_have_previously_created`](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/04/headless-chrome)

Comment: I don't want to use selenium webdriver.  I ran google-chrome-stable --headless --disable-gpu --screenshot https://docs.google.com/drawings/d/the_rest_of_a_URL_to_a_Google_Drawing_I_have_previously_created but that took a screenshot of "Bad Request Error 400". That's not what I want.

Comment: it works ok with my driving `chromium --headless --disable-gpu --screenshot  https://docs.google.com/drawings/d/1oai5ow6B6kWKaHfY6tBtMdfZ56b0hBY4jpiGn1J78HQ` . you can try it - this document is shared to everyone. If I use your URL literaly I get error 400 as well - because such document does not exist. Are you sure you use proper URL ?

Comment: You are right. I was wrong. It works! I mistakenly pasted in 'https://docs.google.com/drawings/d/the_rest_of_a_URL_to_a_Google_Drawing_I_have_previously_created'

Comment: I am on Linux therefore apparently I don't need `--disable-gpu` For more information see https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=737678.

Comment: My chrome works bad sometimes at my linux workstation - it tries to use GPU by default and I had to disable it occasionally (my video driver is i915). Probably bumping from 18.04 to 20.04 (kernel 5.4) resolved it though. So for screenshots it would be safe to disable it because you do not need high speed

Comment: Oh. I see. Thanks for letting me know. I appreciate that.